# Javascript / JQuery if Statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Purpose of the code shown is to add by time some reminder. the cases are for different days of the week  and in that days specific times.
Strange thing some statements are working most not, but i dont see what breaks the code:

```
    function refreshTime() {
  var now = getTime();
  $('#date').html(now.day + ', ' + now.date + '. ' + now.month);
  $('#time').html("<span class='hour'>" + now.hour + "</span>" + "<span class='minute'>" + now.minute + "</span>" + "<span class='second'>" + now.second + "</span>");
  if (now.day != "Sonntag" && now.day != "Samstag")
    {
    if (now.hour == "9" && now.minute >= "50")
      {
      var left = "60" - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      }
    if (now.hour == '11' && now.minute >= '50')
      {
      var left = '60' - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      } 
    if (now.hour == '14' && now.minute >= '50')
      {
      var left = '60' - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      }
    if (now.hour == "17" && now.minute >= "50")
      {
      var left = "60" - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      }
     else
     {
     $('#gh').html("");
     }      
    }
  if (now.day == "Samstag")
    {
    if (now.hour == "9" && now.minute >= "50")
      {
      var left = "60" - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      }
    if (now.hour == "12" && now.minute >= "50")
      {
      var left = "60" - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      } 
    if (now.hour == "13" && now.minute >= "50")
      {
      var left = "60" - now.minute;
      $('#gh').html("<span class='gh_remind'>Grosshandel einstellen in " + left + " Minuten!</span>");
      }     
    else
     {
     $('#gh').html("");
     }         
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is with all of the strings? You are dealing with numbers. "60" and "50" are not numbers!

Comment: Don't compare strings ! '6'>'50'.

Comment: Replace all `if`s (but the first ones) with `else if` - and behold the wonder of JS!

Comment: so does it make a difference if a number  is in "2" to '2'?  From what i know by php it doenst make a  difference  as long as  you stick to one method.....

Comment: Well, if one operand is a number (with `typeof 'number'`), the other is cast to number as well. But the point is all the quote marks in `now.minute >= '50'`-like  expressions in your code are redundant - and confusing: in any case you don't want these to be compared as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var a = 'a', b;
if (a == 'a') {
  b = 'right';
}
if (a == 'c') {
  b = 'wrong';
}
else {
  b = 'FOOBAR!';
}
alert(b);
```

Even though you (probably) expect `b` to store `'right'` value in the end of that `if` structure, it - surprise, surprise! - will contain `FOOBAR` instead. The reason is that if all your `if`s are written like this, they're independent of each other. The first one will assign `'right'` string to `b` variable - but the second one, going through `else` branch, will happily reassign it (to some foobar).

If you want to create a chain of `if`s, use `if - else if - else` syntax instead:

```
var a = 'a', b;
if (a == 'a') {
  b = 'right';
}
else if (a == 'c') {
  b = 'wrong';
}
else {
  b = 'FOOBAR!';
}
alert(b);
```

Now that will show you the `right` thing, right? )

Comment: thx  changed  all  but  first if´s  to else if  and it worked  fine.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are not numbers. Do not use quotes around numbers unless you actually want it to be a string.

```
> console.log("1">"50")
  false
> console.log("9">"50")
  true
```

Comment: also it's always good to be consistent when quoting - use either `"` or `'` but don't mix it. Maybe add a hint on why that fails (lexicographical ordering) and how it's done correctly.